# Get SharePoint page stats?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-platform

In Modern SharePoint, there is an analytics pane that shows a usage report for that specific page. I'd like to create a report of this info for all pages, ideally via Power Automate or Power BI. Everything I've found in my research shows how to get site usage reports, but I need it at the page level. Any advice?